# What is .tt file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, thor

In [bundler/bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler) & [rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails) project, there are some `*.tt` files (Go to the project page, click `t` then type `.tt`). Inside this kind of file, it could use ERB. Example of a `.tt` file (from [bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/templates/newgem/Gemfile.tt)):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in <%=config[:name]%>.gemspec
gemspec
```

What are these `.tt` files? Where are they from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're Thor template files.

The `.tt` could be any file extension you want. It is just because they pick `.tt` as file extension. See [Thor::Actions#template](http://textmate.rubyforge.org/thor/Thor/Actions.html#M000066) to learn more.

[A Real world example from bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli/gem.rb).